# Line By Line output Python Regex

Tags: python, regex, printing, output, multiline

I am trying to figure out the best way to get the output to match in python using a few regex matches. Here is an example text.

```
Student ID: EDITED Sex: TRUCK

<<Fall 2016: 20160822 to 2

Rpt Dup

CRIJ    3310 Foundtns of Criminal Justice           3 A         


COMM    3315 Leadership Communication               3 B         


ENGL    3430 Professional Writing                   4 A         


<<Spring 2017: 20170117 to 20170512  () >>


MKTG    3303 Principles of Marketing                3 B         

<<Summer 2017: 20170515 to 20170809  () >>


HUMA    4300 Selected Topics in Humanities          3           


<<Fall 2017: 20170828 to 20171215  () >>

HUMA    4317 The Modern Era                         3           


COMM 

4314 Intercultrl Communicatn                3      
(((IT REPEATS THE SAME TYPE OF TEXT BUT WITH A DIFFERENT STUDENT BELOW)))
```

Here is some code:

```
import re
term_match = re.findall(r'^<<.*', filename, re.M)
course_match = re.findall(r'^[A-Z]{2,7}.*', filename, re.M

print('\n'.join(term_match))
print('\n'.join(course_match))
```

I have a regex to match the student ID and the Course info, my problem is getting them to be outputted in line by line order. On the document there are multiple students with lots of coursework so just matching is not good enough. I need to match ID, print the following coursework matches, and then print the next ID and coursework when it gets to that line. Any help on how to achieve such a thing would be great!

Comment: Some code would be helpful to see where you got stuck. Generally, just read your file line by line check if it matches the student pattern and print the student ID if it does, otherwise use your other pattern to pick up and print the course info.

Comment: Could you show the raw string using the correct markdown formatting.

Comment: I have added both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flag `re.MULTILINE` will let the regex span multiple lines.

That said, you're probably better off looping line-by-line and recognizing when each new student id is encountered:

```
student_id = ''
for line in s.splitlines(False):
    if not line:
        continue
    elif line.startswith('STUDENT'):
        student_id = line[7:].strip()
    else:
        print(student_id, line)
```

One other thought, you could simplify the problem by dividing the text into chunks (one per student id):

```
starts = [mo.start() for mo in re.finditer(r'^STUDENT ID(.*)$', s, re.MULTILINE)]
starts.append(len(s))

chunks = []
for begin, end in zip(starts, starts[1:]):
    chunks.append(s[begin:end])
```

After that, isolating the courses for each student should be much easier :-)

Comment: This is great! I am just tweaking it now because the courses are repeating but thats on me!